# JSON.parse to Map howto (new syntax 0.3.1_r17328)

Tags: dart

What's the new syntax for the following please? :

```
Map mAcctData = JSON.parse(sResponse);    // sResponse is Json String
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`parse` (and `stringify`) has been moved to a top-level function.

```dart
import 'dart:json' as JSON;  // note the JSON name

main() {
  var text = // some text...
  var map = JSON.parse(text); // using the JSON name
}
```

or

```dart
import 'dart:json'; // note, no JSON name

main() {
  var text = // some text...
  var map = parse(text); // calling parse as a top-level function.
}
```